Is the category of small $\mathcal{U}$-categories a category? (According to Kashiwara and Schapira's conventions)
$\def\C{\mathcal{C}}
\def\D{\mathcal{D}}
\def\U{\mathcal{U}}
\def\mor{\operatorname{mor}}
\def\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}$I am having trouble with set-theoretic size issues and conventions regarding the “category of categories” considered in Kashiwara, Schapira, Categories and Sheaves, Remark 1.3.5 (stated below). Here are the relevant definitions to understand what the remark says, taken from the same book:

Definition 1.1.1. A universe $\mathcal{U}$ is a set satisfying the following properties:

$\emptyset \in \mathcal{U}$,
$u \in \mathcal{U}$ implies $u \subset \mathcal{U}$, (equivalently, $x \in \mathcal{U}$ and $y \in x$ implies $y \in \mathcal{U}$, or else $\mathcal{U} \subset \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{U})$)
$u \in \mathcal{U}$ implies $\{u\} \in \mathcal{U}$,
$u \in \mathcal{U}$ implies $\mathcal{P}(u) \in \mathcal{U}$,
if $I \in \mathcal{U}$ and $u_i \in \mathcal{U}$ for all $i \in I$, then $\bigcup_{i \in I} u_i \in \mathcal{U}$,
$\mathbb{N} \in \mathcal{U}$.


(Where the elements of $\mathbb{N}$ are defined as usual in set theory.) After this definition, the authors acknowledge that the book will work within the framework of ZFC plus the axiom of universes:
(UA). For any set $X$, there exists a universe $\U$ such that $X\in\U$.

Definition 1.1.2. Let $\U$ be a universe.

A set is called a $\U$-set if it belongs to $\U$.
A set is called $\U$-small if it is isomorphic to a set belonging to $\U$.

Definition 1.2.1. A category $\C$ consists of:

A set $\operatorname{Ob}(\C)$,
For any $X,Y\in\operatorname{Ob}(\C)$, a set $\Hom_\C(X,Y)$,
(...)


From which it follows that the collection of morphisms $\operatorname{Mor}(\C)$ for any category $\C$ must be a set.

A category $\C$ is called a $\U$-category if $\Hom_\C(X,Y)$ is $\U$-small for any $X,Y\in\operatorname{Ob}(\C)$.
A $\U$-small category is a $\U$-category $\C$ such that $\operatorname{Ob}(\C)$ is $\U$-small.

Equivalently, a $\U$-small category is a category such that $\operatorname{Mor}(\C)$ is $\U$-small. Now the remark I am interested on:

Remark 1.3.5. Consider the category $\mathcal{U}$-$\mathbf{Cat}$ whose objects are the small $\mathcal{U}$-categories and the morphisms are the functors of such categories, that is,
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{U}\text{-}\mathbf{C a t}}\left(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{C}^{\prime}\right)=\operatorname{Fct}\left(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{C}^{\prime}\right)
$$
Since $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{U}\text{-}\mathbf{Cat}}\left(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{C}^{\prime}\right)$ is not only a set, but is in fact a category, $\mathcal{U}$-$\mathbf{Cat}$ is not only a category, it has a structure of a so-called $2$-category. We shall not develop the theory of $2$-categories in this book.

In particular, the remark affirms that $\mathcal{U}$-$\mathbf{Cat}$ is a category; and in turn, this means that $\operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{U}\text{-}\mathbf{Cat})$ is a set (because of Definition 1.2.1 from above). But this is not the case. Indeed, since $\mathbb{N}\in\U$, we have $n\in\U$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. In particular, all finite sets (regarded as discrete categories) are $\U$-small categories, thus all finite sets are members of $\operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{U}\text{-}\mathbf{Cat})$. But the collection of finite sets is not a set.
Gaillard's expansion on [KS] seems to hint at a possible solution. In [G, Chapter 2, p. 10], he says the whole document [G] adheres to the following variation on [KS] definition:

A $\U$-category is a category $\C$ such that, for all objects
$X$, $Y$, the set $\Hom_\C (X, Y )$ is a $\U$-set.
A category $\C$ is $\U$-small if [it is a $\U$-category and] the set of
objects of $\C$ is a $\U$-set. More concisely: $\C$ is $\U$-small if and only if $\C \in \U$.

If we follow Gaillard's conventions, we have:

$\U$-$\mathbf{Cat}$ is a true category, i.e., $\operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{U}\text{-}\mathbf{Cat})$ is now an actual set.

If it happens that $\operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{U}\text{-}\mathbf{Cat})\not\in\U$, we can make use of (UA) and take a universe $\mathcal{V}$ such that $\U\in\mathcal{V}$. Now $\U$-$\mathbf{Cat}$ is a $\mathcal{V}$-small category.


Even though Gaillard's account [G] seems meticulous, he doesn't address Remark 1.3.5 nor my problem with it (at least I couldn't find a mention). My questions are:

Am I getting anything wrong? I don't have much experience with set theory nor universes (about the latter I learnt just as of today).

If indeed $\U$-$\mathbf{Cat}$ isn't a category with [KS]'s conventions: Does the workaround from above sound reasonable? Do you have any alternative ideas to solve the issue?


References
[KS] Kashiwara, Schapira, Categories and Sheaves
[G] Pierre-Yves Gaillard, About “Categories and Sheaves” https://vixra.org/abs/1602.0067

Interestingly, [KS]'s convention predates to SGA4, see Exp. I, 1.0, 1.1.

Yes, I agree that if a category has a set of objects and you want a category of $\mathcal U$-small categories, you will need to insist that your small categories have a genuine $\mathcal U$-set of objects, and not just a $\mathcal U$-small such set.
